# Hide event handler is not fired

Tags: jquery, html

I have three `div`s and when the second `div`'s `display` attribute turns from `block` to `none`, which should trigger the `hide` event in jQuery, it doesn't have any response.

HTML code:

```
<div class="datetimepicker datetimepicker-dropdown-bottom-left dropdown-menu" style="left: 1094.421875px; z-index: 10;"></div>
<div class="datetimepicker datetimepicker-dropdown-bottom-left dropdown-menu" style="left: 389.140625px; z-index: 10; display: none; top: 216px;"></div>
<div class="datetimepicker datetimepicker-dropdown-bottom-left dropdown-menu" style="left: -134px; z-index: 10;"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.datetimepicker').on('hide', function () {
    $("body").css('position', '');
    $("body").css('width', '');
})
```

Comment: which library you are using for datetimepicker

Comment: Where did you find `hide` event in jQuery?

Comment: @wqz, could you explain clearly what exactly needs to be done.

Comment: My problem is how to trigger an event when the 'display' turned from 'block' to 'none'?

Answer (score 0):

pay attention that *hide* and *show* are not standard DOM events. in jQuery you can bind them to any element but *hide* or *show* event will not be triggered when you hide or show element by jQuery or other methods.
like this sample code

```js
  // Bind hide event to element
  $('#sample_element_id').bind('hide', function() {
    $('#result').append('<li style="color:red;">Hide event triggered!!!</li>');
  });

function test(magic) {
  //clear report list
  $('#result li').remove();
  
  if(magic) {
    //The magic code to add show/hide custom event triggers
    (function ($) {
   $.each(['show', 'hide'], function (i, ev) {
     var el = $.fn[ev];
     $.fn[ev] = function () {
       this.trigger(ev);
       return el.apply(this, arguments);
     };
   });
    })(jQuery);
    $('button').remove();
  } else {
    $('button#nomagic').remove();  
  }
  
  $('#result').append('<li>Hiding with jQuery</li>');
  // Hide element using jQuery Hide method
  $('#sample_element_id').hide();
  
  $('#sample_element_id').show();
  
  $('#result').append('<li>Hiding with Css display</li>');
  // Hide element using css display style
  $('#sample_element_id').css('display', 'none');
  
  $('#sample_element_id').css('display', 'block');
  
  $('#result').append('<li>Hiding with adding Css class</li>');
  // Hide element using css display style
  $('#sample_element_id').addClass('hidden');
  
  //reset test element for next test
  $('#sample_element_id').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#sample_element_id').removeAttr('style');
  $('#sample_element_id').show();
  
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample_element_id">TEST</div>
<hr>
<button id="nomagic" onclick="test(false);">Test Without Magic Code</button>
<button id="magic" onclick="test(true);">Test With Magic Code</button>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

change visibility of element by jQuery functions, css class or style and other methods did not trigger *Hide* or *Show* event in jQuery.

but you can add this events to jQuery with a magic javascript code. then with calling jQuery *hide* and *show* methods, binded events will be triggered. view this [sample code](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-trigger-custom-event-show-hide-element/) for more details.